# Cannot read property of "undefined" even though the object IS defined! [React]

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to generate the markup for a dropdown menu that will allow users to change the language/locale of the site.

But my component will not render because the browser is telling me the object (language) I'm trying to pull country names (locales) off of is undefined.

What I don't understand is that when I console log that same language object and the key that I'm passing to it (selectedLang) in the lines above, they both print out just fine.

Here is my code:

```
compileAvailableLocales() {
        let locales = availableLangs;
        let selectedLang = this.props.lang;
        console.log("selectedLang: ", selectedLang, typeof selectedLang);
        console.log("availableLangs: ", availableLangs);
        console.log("language: ", language);

        let markup = locales.map( (loc) => {
            let readableName = language[ selectedLang ].navigation.locales[ loc ];

            return (
                <li
                  key={ loc }
                  value={ loc }
                  onMouseDown={ this.handleLangChange }>
                    { readableName }
                </li>
            );
        });

        return markup;
    }
```

I think the problem may be the way that I am importing the language object from my **essential_lang.js** file.

I'm importing into the index.jsx file (see code above) with this line:

```
import { language } from '../../constants/essential_lang'
```

And here is some of the code from that file:

```
   export const language = {
    'de_de': {
        footer: {
            links: [
                {
                    title: 'KUNDENSERVICE',
                    endpoint: 'mailto:kundenservice@spinmaster.com'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Datenschutz',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/privacy'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Impressum und Allgemeine Geschäftsbedingungen',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/terms'
                }
            ],
            copyright: 'Spin Master Ltd. All Rights Reserved.'
        },
        fourohfour: {
            heading: 'Oh Noes!',
            message: 'This page doesn\'t exist.',
            gohome: 'Back Home'
        },
        loading: "Loading",
        navigation: {
            menuitems: [
                {
                    title: 'Videos',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/videos/'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Colleggtibles',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/colleggtibles'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Produkte',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/toys/'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Hilfe/Häufig gestellte Fragen',
                    endpoint: 'https://spinmastersupport.helpshift.com/a/hatchimals/?p=web&l=de'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Eltern',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/parents/'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Spiele',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/activities/'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Wo erhältlich',
                    endpoint: '/de_de/where-to-buy/'
                }
            ],
            locales: {
                de_de: 'Deutschland',
                en_au: 'Australia',
                en_ca: 'Canada',
                en_uk: 'United Kingdom',
                en_us: 'United States',
                es_es: 'España',
                es_mx: 'México',
                fr_fr: 'France',
                it_it: 'Italia',
                nl_nl: 'Dutch',
                tr_tr: 'Türkiye'
            }
        }
    },
    'en_au': { ...
```

Here is output for the console.logs:

Comment: where you defined `language` ?

Comment: I'm importing it from a json file at the top of the module:

import { language } from '../../constants/essential_lang'

Comment: that contains `navigation` key inside `language[ selectedLang ]`?

Comment: I added some more code to the initial question. You can see that language["de_de"].navigation should provide access to a menuItems object.

Comment: check the complete this, `language[ selectedLang ].navigation.locales[ loc ];` means navigation should contain a key locales, selectedLang should contain a proper key. tell me one thing are you getting undefined or null for `selectedLang` in console any time ?

Comment: does your `navigation` key contain a `locales` key? please post the entire value for the `navigation` key in `essential_lang.js`

Comment: Yes, it does. I went ahead and added the rest of the code for the entiure "de_de" property (but left out the other languages, as they are the same, just different copy)

Comment: now the whole doubt is only on the `selectedLang` value, check it should not have `null` or `undefined` as initial value.

Comment: all three of the console.logs return values. nothing is undefined. that is why i'm so confused.

Answer (score -1):

Is it as simple as returning a string?

```
return "
            <li
              key={ loc }
              value={ loc }
              onMouseDown={ this.handleLangChange }>
                { readableName }
            </li>
        ";
```

Difficult without seeing all the code.

Comment: no, that is not the problem. The code is breaking because language variable is undefined. I think Mayanek is right. It probably has something to do with the way I'm importing that variable from outside this file.

Comment: I've added more code to the initial question, in case that clarifies the problem.

Comment: Also, I believe the solution you provided would need to be wrapped in ( ) , not quotes, if you want that jsx to still execute correctly

Comment: The OP is using React and JSX.

Comment: Ah right. Apologies. I have no experience of those.